# Client Assertion verify the signature failed

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have configured app registration with client certificate .cer file in azure

Using jwt.io to create client assertion, and requested access token as in below screenshot

[image]

There were few posts about issues with key not found, but in this scenario key Is not able to generate signature. unable to understand the issue here. I used private key and public key in jwt.to to generate client assertion.

Header in JWt used base64 thumbprint value-

```
 {
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "x5t": "hfbTrE31AcSETk1BFhovA1w1SMc="
}
```

However, signature is verified in jwt.io.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out, its issue in Private/public key. Extract Private key as PKCS #8 to use in building jwt assertion.

[image]

Verify Signature gives error with encrypted Private key, use decrypted private key

[image]